# How do I assign a value to a boost::units::si::angular_acceleration?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-units

In boost units, I usually assign values by multiplying with one of the static consts:

e.g.

```
using namespace boost::units;
quantity<si::angular_velocity> av = 0.5 * si::radians_per_second;
```

But how can I do it when there is no multiplier const defined?

e.g. This doesn't compile because boost::units::si::radians_per_second_per_second isn't defined.

```
quantity<si::angular_acceleration> aa = 0.5 * si::radians_per_second_per_second;
```

Comment: I fail to even get your first example to compile.

Comment: Does `0.5 * si::radians_per_second / si::seconds` work?

Comment: sorry @pmr, I had quantity<> missing, I've simplified my example.

Answer (score 1):

As @celtschk suggested in the comments, the units can be assigned by applying the correct operation to the units multipliers:

```
quantity<si::angular_acceleration> aa = 0.5 * si::radians_per_second / si::seconds;
```